# What's the word for believing based on preconceptions rather than objectively?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for when a person chooses to believe something based on preconceptions rather than judging it objectively?

Here's an example (a little contrived but hopefully illustrates the point):

A person ,P, is usually very healthy and prides themself on eating good, healthy food. This person has two friends, A and B, and they share a house.

P is in awe of A and pretty much anything A does is "right". For example, if A buys a drink that's packed with sugar but looks "healthy" then they decide this drink is super-healthy and there's now always a carton of this drink on P's shelf in the fridge.

However, they're not so keen on B. B buys some food that's super-healthy. P doesn't even bother tasting this food and it never gets touched, despite being on the sharing shelf.

Comment: I think "prejudice" might apply.  Also, "hero worship".

Answer (score 1):

It's almost in your title.

**[preconceived](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preconceived)**

> ADJECTIVE
>   (Of an idea or opinion) formed before having the evidence for its truth or usefulness:
>   the same set of facts can be tailored to fit any preconceived belief

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ***[prejudice](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prejudice):***

> - any preconceived opinion or feeling, either favorable or unfavorable.

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

**Biased** is the word that comes to my mind when a person is not objective.

From your example, person P is unfair in treating person B's food even though B's food is super healthy. So P is biased towards person A's choices.

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/biased) dictionary defines *biased* as,

> Showing an unreasonable like or dislike for a person based on personal opinions.